# Full Text Search in Bing API

Tags: full-text-search, bing-api

I am using Bing API to implement search in my application.I am not able to implement full text search in this. For example if i searched employee then in the results employees should also be there but in the result only employee is present.

Comment: Did you search inside your hosted data or inside whole internet? For hosted data I could recommend http://indexden.com